# How to show all same values from a column in sql?

Tags: sql

I have a table `Group`

```
group  no -of -win
------ ---
a      3
b      3
c      4
```

How can I show

```
group
---------
a
b
```

as output? That is, the set of groups that have the same number of wins.

Comment: Missing: RBMDS and version. There can be many different values in `no_of_win` shared by more than one group. *"groups that have the same number of wins"* is ambiguous. Please clarify.

Answer (score -1):

use self join

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ad99c7d16afdab7ddf9904eadd05b645)**

```
select distinct a.group from tablename a
join tablename b where a.group<>b.group and a.noofwin=b.noofwin
```

OUTPUT:

```
grp
a
b
```

Comment: I think you should add `DISTINCT` in case there are more than 2 groups with the same number of wins

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, yes right you are. Edited it .thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT GroupName
FROM Groups a
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Groups b WHERE b.GroupName <> a.GroupName AND b.Score = a.Score)
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22411919)